# Google Forms: Number Ranges Appear as Dates

Tags: google-forms

I have a Google form intended to be filled out by teachers.  One of the questions is about student ages.  The choices are checkboxes with age ranges, so [ ] 0 - 5, [ ] 6 - 11 and so on.

The two ranges 6 - 11 and 12 - 14 show up formatted as dates, 11-Jun and 14-Dec, in the CSV spreadsheet.  The others (0 - 5, 15 - 19, and 20+) show up as text.  If I format the entire column as text, I get the numbers 43262 and 43448, which are presumably day numbers.

Since the munged content is predictable, I know I can fix this manually, but I'd surely like to prevent it from happening.  How can I prevent this behavior?

**Edit:**
Here's what the form looks like:
[image]

The resulting spreadsheet looks like this before formatting:
[image]

After formatting column B as text, it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use forced formatting so instead just **`6 - 11`** / **`12 - 14`** type in:

**`="6 - 11"`**
**`="12 - 14"`**

or:

**`'6 - 11`**
**`'12 - 14`**

or:

**`=TEXT(; "6 - 11")`**
**`=TEXT(; "12 - 14")`**

or:

**`=T("6 - 11")`**
**`=T("12 - 14")`**

---

**update:**

you can try to format it as **@**

[image]

or you can fake it to still be a date but look like you need it:

[image]

Comment: Might want to edit the first two parts out so people can immediately see what worked.